# Algorithm in JavaScript 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

You are the owner of a coworking space like WeWork and your office building is rectangular. 
Your team just built wall partitions to create mini offices for startups. 
This office campus is represented by a 2D array of 1s (floor spaces) and 0s (walls). 
Each point on this array is a one foot by one foot square. 
You need to calculate the number of offices. 
A single office is bordered by walls and is constructed by placing floors next to each other, 
horizontally and/or vertically. 
Two 1s adjacent to each other horizontally or vertically are always part of the same office.

Function numOffices() has one parameter: grid - a 2D grid/array of 1s and 0s

In this problem, our input format is as follows: The first line is the number of rows in the 2D array. The second line is the number of columns in the 2D array. The rest of the input contains the data to be processed.

Here is an example of the raw input:

```
4 
5 
11110 
11010 
11000 
00000
```

> Expected: Output returns the number of valid offices in the grid.

Constraints

```
Assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by walls. 
Assume that the bounds of the array are the following: 
The total amount of elements in the array: width x height <= 10^6
```

Example numOffices() Input

```
4
5
11110
00000
00100
00011
```

Example Output

```
3
```

Solution

```
There's 3 offices in this grid, one made of four 1s on the top left, 
one made of one 1 in the middle, and one made of two 1s in the bottom right.
```

**Write a function numOffices() to solve this problem.**

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: You have not described a problem, only asked for help. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ This looks like a course question which you are asking SO contributors to write the code for you _ If that's the case then unfortunately that's not what this website is about _ Please add the code that YOU have already tried yourself _ Visit SO Help Center for more guidelines >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://developers.turing.com/dashboard/takechallenge

Comment: This is a test from https://developers.turing.com/dashboard/takechallenge

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Find the solution below

```js
/**
 * @param {character[][]} grid
 * @return {number}
 */

function numOffices(grid) {
    let result = 0;
    //Put your code here.
    let markIsland = function (grid, x, y, visited) {
        if (x < 0 || x > grid.length - 1 || y < 0 || y > grid[x].length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        if (visited[x][y] === true) {
            return;
        }
        visited[x][y] = true;
        if (grid[x][y] === '0') {
            return;
        }
        markIsland(grid, x - 1, y, visited);
        markIsland(grid, x + 1, y, visited);
        markIsland(grid, x, y - 1, visited);
        markIsland(grid, x, y + 1, visited);
    };

    let visited = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        visited[i] = [];
    }
    for (let x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < grid[x].length; y++) {
            if (!visited[x][y] && grid[x][y] === '1') {
                result++;
                markIsland(grid, x, y, visited);
            }
            visited[x][y] = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
};

let height = parseInt(readline());
let width = parseInt(readline());
let grid = [];
for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    grid[i] = (readline() || "").split("");
}

print(numOffices(grid));
```

NOTICE: Copying and pasting may make you pass the test but looking through the script to study and maybe improve on it will make you a better developer

Comment: really curious how did you get the thought process sort out. do you mind sharing the thought process that you use to break down the issues. i was only able reach the top,bottom,right,left as show in markIsland.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simpler version for solving the problem:

```
function numOffices(grid) {
  let result = 0;

  for (let x = 0; x < grid[0].length; x++) {
    if (grid[0][x] === 1 && grid[0][x - 1] !== 1) {
      result = result + 1;
    }
  }

  for (let y = 1; y < grid.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < grid[0].length; x++) {
      if (grid[y][x] === 1 && grid[y][x - 1] !== 1 && grid[y - 1][x] !== 1) {
        result = result + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

let grid = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
];

console.log(numOffices(grid));
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```js
function numOffices(grid) {
    let result = 0;
    const gridHeight = grid.length;
    const gridLength = grid[0].length;

    for (var y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < gridLength; x++){
            const item = grid[y][x]

            if (item === 1){
                result = result + 1

                markRoom(null, x, y, grid)
            }
        }
    }

    console.log({result})
    return result;
};

function markRoom(from, x, y, grid){

    const item = grid[y][x]
    const gridHeight = grid.length;
    const gridLength = grid[0].length;

    if (item !== 1){
        return
    }

    grid[y][x] = -1

    if (from !== 'top' && y !== 0){
        markRoom('down', x, y-1, grid)
    }

    if (from !== 'right' && x!== gridLength -1){
        markRoom('left',x+1, y, grid)
    }

    if (from !== 'down' && y!== gridHeight-1){
        markRoom('up',x, y+1, grid)
    }

    if (from !== 'left' && x!== 0){
        markRoom('right',x-1, y, grid);
    }
}

const grid = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]

console.log(numOffices(grid))
```